# Norm inequality with wedge product

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, normed-spaces, exterior-algebra

Anyone could help me to prove this following inequality?

$\displaystyle\frac{||(u+v)\wedge w||}{||u+v||}\le \frac{||u\wedge w||}{||u||} +\frac{||v\wedge w||}{||v||}  $

where $u\wedge v$ is the [wedge (cross) product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wedge_product) of $u$ and $v$ and
here we use Euclidean norm in $\mathbb{R}^n$ 
$||u||=\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n u_i^2}$,

$||u\wedge v|| = \sqrt{\sum_{1 \le i < j \le n} \left(u_iv_j-u_jv_i \right)^2 }$

Comment: Hint: You need to apply the triangle inequality a couple of times. First apply it to $\frac{u}{\|u+v\|} \wedge w$ and $\frac{v}{\|u+v\|} \wedge w$. Next multiply two terms by $1$ in different and clever ways, then apply the triangle inequality twice more to get what you want.

Comment: but i think that you will get the wrong direction of the triangle inequality: $||x+y||\ge ||x||+||y||$!!

Comment: Oh yes, my comment is nonsense! Sorry! Bon... why do you think this inequality is true? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Isn't the inequality false? Take $w = v$, then $v \wedge w  = 0$ and the inequality holds if and only if
$$
\frac{\|u \wedge v\|}{\|u + v\|} \leq \frac{\|u\wedge v\|}{\|u\|}.
$$
This holds if and only if $\| u \| \leq \|u + v\|$, and if we take $v = -\frac 12 u$ then that's not true.